# How to use NIntegrate inside FindRoot?

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, warning-messages

I am trying to use `FindRoot` on functions that involve `NIntegrate`, and Mathematica is throwing undesirable errors even when it gets an answer. I have tried the trick of using `_?NumericQ` for the function parameters, but the errors remain. What's the "correct" way to do this, so that Mathematica doesn't throw errors?

For example:

`f[x_?NumericQ]=NIntegrate[Sin[x t^2]/Log[t],{t,2,3}]`

Plotting `f[x]` for $6<x<7,$ we see there is a root near 6.7:

[image]

So we solve for the root:

`FindRoot[f[x],{x,6.7}]`

Mathematica gives the correct answer after throwing three errors:

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand Sin[a x^2]/Log[x] has evaluated to
>   non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with
>   boundaries {{2,3}}.
>
> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand (x^2 Cos[a x^2])/Log[x] has evaluated
>   to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with
>   boundaries {{2,3}}.
>
> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy
>   after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} =
>   {4.00000008967591079907500673086366820702108881846470467280596494675}.
>   NIntegrate obtained 3.1051550219984847`*^-16 and
>   3.7022326395320475`*^-13 for the integral and error estimates.

I'm mainly interested in getting rid of the first two, since the third seems to go away after fiddling with WorkingPrecision, PrecisionGoal, and AccuracyGoal. But as I'm fairly new to this, insight on all three would be appreciated.

Comment: version 11.3 ,just `FindRoot[NIntegrate[Sin[x t^2]/Log[t], {t, 2, 3}], {x, 6.7}]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just change the function definition to `SetDelayed`

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Sin[x t^2]/Log[t], {t, 2, 3}]
FindRoot[f[x], {x, 6.7}]
(*{x -> 6.74481}*)
```

Comment: Ok, I see what's going on. I tried this and at first it didn't work. Then I cleared all variables/functions and it worked. I think I had previous versions stored of the same functions without `SetDelayed` that were being applied when the newer definitions with `SetDelayed` were failing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
f = Interpolation[
  Table[{x, NIntegrate[Sin[x t^2]/Log[t], {t, 2, 3}]}, {x, 6.6, 6.8, 0.05}]]
```

and then the following:

```
FindRoot[f[x] == 0, {x, 6.8}]

(*   {x -> 6.7448}    *)
```

Have fun!